# import/export of external types failing in jest unit tests (vue2)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, rollup, module-export

I'm trying to create a package which exports some types, enums, consts and interfaces I use across multiple projects.

So I created a `main.ts` and I put all the exports there, specify it in package.json: `"main": "main.ts"`.

One of my exports needs some `mapbox-gl` types. Obviously, I don't want my package to include `mapbox-gl` types. So I did the following:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "mapbox-gl": "^1.13.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/mapbox-gl": "^1.13.0",
}
```

Inside `main.ts`, I do:

```ts
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";

export interface DataSourceOptions {
  shouldLoad?: boolean;
  name: string;
  map: mapboxgl.Map;
  layer: mapboxgl.Layer;
}
```

I published my package, imported it in my project and it works as expected.
Until I try to test any of the components using this package.

Jest is throwing the following error:

> D:\path\to\project\node_modules\some-custom-package\main.ts:1
> ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I tried to fix this by specifying my package in the `transformIgnorePatterns` of `jest.config.js`:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw" +
    "|some-custom-package" +
    ")/)",
],
```

However, I'm still seeing the same error.

I've also tried bundling my package with `rollup`, using either `tsc` and `rollup-plugin-typescript2` plugins, because I know in `rollup` I can use `externals` to declare `mapbox-gl` as such. For some unknown reason, neither `tsc` nor `rollup-plugin-typescript2` seem to declare my interfaces, they only declare `const`s, `type`s and `enum`s ([possibly related](https://github.com/ezolenko/rollup-plugin-typescript2/issues/24)).

I know it looks like multiple questions into one but I'm only looking for a solution.

- either resolve jest's problem in importing my package (again, what I have works quite well in the actual app - it only fails in tests)
- or find a way to keep interfaces while bundling my exports with rollup and declaring `mapbox-gl` as external

---

A possible workaround I see would be to circumvent the mapboxgl import in my package, by making the types I use from it dynamic:

```
export interface DataSourceOptions<M,L> {
  shouldLoad?: boolean;
  name: string;
  map: M;
  layer: L;
}
```

and, in my project go: `options: DataSourceOptions<mapboxgl.Map, mapboxgl.Layer>`, but I don't really like this solution, to be fair. It circumvents the problem, it doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by setting:

```
"type": "module"
```

in the the modules' `package.json`, together with adding it to `transformIgnorePatterns` in `jest.config.js` of the project consuming it, as shown above.